# Mocking RestTemplate postforEntity

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a service class which looks like -

```
class A {
   @Autowired
   RestTemplate restTemplate;
   public void method() {
       res = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://abc", entity, Employee.class);
       resBody = res.getBody();      
   }
}
```

Following is the Test Class for it-

```
class TestA {
   @Mock
   RestTemplate restTemplate;
   @InjectMocks
   A obj;
   void testMethod1() {
       res = ....
       when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), any()).thenReturn(res);
   }
   void testMethod2() {
       res = ....
       when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), any()).thenReturn(res);
   }
}
```

testMethod1 fails throwing NullPointerException on "res.getBody() from A.method()" while testMethod2 runs successfully

Why is any() not working here while anyString() works? I thought any() works for any data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look into the [Javadocs for `RestTemplate`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-web/latest/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). There are three `postForEntity` methods:

- `postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Map<String,?> uriVariables)`
- `postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)`
- `postForEntity(URI url, Object request, Class<T> responseType)`

Your mock in `testMethod2` catches for sure one of the first both methods. However the mock in your `testMethod1` seems to cover the method with an `URI` as first parameter and well, therefore your `restTemplate.postForEntity("http://abc", entity, Employee.class)` does not match.

If you are interested in what method is currently mocked, just type a line, e. g. `restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), any())` and then just hover over the method in your favourite IDE to see already at compile time, which exact (overridden) method was covered.

Comment: Spot on!! I changed the service method to restTemplate.postForEntity(new URI("http://abc"), entity, Employee.class) and testMethod1 started working. Is there any way to know which function definition is being mocked by Mockito?

Comment: Yeah of course, just see the last section in my now updated answer. Feel free to either upvote if this answers the question of your last comment or if there is anything yet unclear!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was similar, casting null to String worked for me:
`when(restTemplateMock.postForEntity((String)isNull(), any(), eq(List.class)))`
`.thenReturn(responseEntityMock);`